# Mount serial port through ssh connection (Mac/Linux)

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, serial-port

I'm working on a MacBook Pro under mountain lion and I would like to mount serial device connected (/dev/ttyUSBx) on a Linux PC under Ubuntu 12.10 through SSH.

I tried with sshfs to mount /dev (linux) on my mac but I don't have permission for serial port.

Is there a way I can create on my Mac fake serial port?

Answer (score 2):

Mount??? You can mount disks, not ports... 
Take a look here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/154573/serial-port-forwarding-over-tcp-ip-linux-server